# Swift 3.0 , Xcode 8.1 , UiNavigation as Tab Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I am building an app and I am very new. I have UINavigation and UITabBarController in the app. Tab bar controller works I want it to work and I also want the uinavigation working just like the tab bar, because I could not come up with anything works like the tab bar on the top of the view.

Here is my what I have now:

[image]

Comment: You need to embed `UINavigationController` with all tab bar controllers exists in app. Then only you will navigate on other controller

Comment: @cagatayodabasi I approved your edit suggestion. I removed the "thanks", because these [should be removed completely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/168333). Also, when there's an image link in a post, you can inline the image by adding a "!" in front of the link. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

Your `UITabBar` contains both of your views "Videos" & "Timer". Your Timer UIViewController should be embedded in a `UINavigationController`. Once you have this, you may add `UIBarButton`s to your navigation bar. However, these will only be visible while you have the Timer tab selected, so it will not work just like the tab bar.